# Inserting user input in Java lottery program

Tags: java, arrays

Here is a code ive completed a long time ago. However, im trying to revisit my Java coding knowledge and even enhance my knowledge using 2D arrays. Ive been trying to improve my code to a new level using 2D arrays, and would like someone to help me how please. Here is what I want to add:

-Allow the user to choose how many tickets they will be generating (ive already done that).
-Randomize to generate the tickets from 1-50. These will be stored in 2d array
-Program will generate 6 numbers for the winning number stored in a 1D array.
-The program will check each ticket to check how many winning numbers there were and store that as in the last position of the 2D array (so 7 locations [x][7])

If you take a look at the do-while loop, this is where im having trouble incorporating into my program with array.

Your assistance is appreciated!

```
Scanner entry=new Scanner(System.in); 
int ticketAmnt;
        
do
{
    System.out.println("How many tickets will you be generating?");
    ticketAmnt = entry.nextInt();
}
while(ticketAmnt<1 || ticketAmnt>100);

int[] lottery = new int[6];
int randomNum;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
{
    // Random number created here.
    randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 50); 
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) 
    {
        // If random number is same, another number generated.
        randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 50);
    }
    lottery[i] = randomNum;
}

for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++)
    System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
```

Comment: if randomNum is same -> actually, you are automatically overwriting it, you are not checking whether or not the values are the same, and the first randomNum is lost. I'm not entirely clear on what you try to do, so I won't make any further guesses

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is not a useful error description. What do you want to accomplish? What does your code currently do and how does that differ from what you'd like it to do?

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Please take a look at the do-while loop. I want the code to take that user-input and store it in a 2D array to generate the amount of tickets entered by the user. After that, I would like the program to generate the ticket numbers 1-49, these will be stored in a 2d array.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper the current code just displays the 6 numbers without the user's input. I want the program to include the user's input and incorprate 2D arrays aswell

Comment: Again, what is the exact problem that you're having that prevents you from doing that? You are currently generating six tickets, and you know how to do that. It should be trivial to generate a different amount of tickets if you have the number of tickets you want to generate stored in a variable. Which you do, actually.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper The problem is rather than generating tickets like above, I want the program to take the user's input seen in the do-while loop and generate this amount of tickets based on the user's entry. I would like this to be stored in 2D arrays

Comment: @Newusersda since you don't provide code that accepts input from the user, it's logical that isn't shown

Comment: @Newusersda that's not a problem, that is just something you haven't coded yet.

Comment: Yes, you already said that. Again, what is making it impossible for you to do that? You know how to generate a specific number of tickets. You have the number of tickets you want to generate stored in `ticketAmnt`. Now, what could you do with the ticket generation loop and the `ticketAmnt`variable so that the loop generates `ticketAmnt` tickets instead of 6 tickets?

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper the number 6 is the numbers generated within a single lottery ticket. I want to take the user's input for how many tickets they want generated, and generate 6 numbers within each ticket from 1-49. This will be stored in a 2d array ([][]), which will later on generate other 6 numbers and the program determine how many winning lottery tickets were acheived.

Comment: So, what you're saying is you need another loop where you use `ticketAmnt`to repeat your ticket generation a number of times equal to `ticketAmnt`. Well, you haven't coded that, but you should know how, since you know how to make loops.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve user input in java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
System.out.println("Enter a number: "); // print something just before the input prompt to guide the user if needed
String input = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input
int number = Integer.parseInt(input); // Need to parseInt because it is read in as a string
scanner.close(); // close the scanner object
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp 
If you need to read multiple inputs then you can put the `scanner.nextLine()` in a loop 
Does this solve your problem?